# Magento is not sending order confirmation emails

Tags: email, magento

I'm using Aschroder SMTP Pro on my Magento site. The test for email sending(that the plugin does) is successful but order confirmation emails are not being sent.
I enabled email and exception log but i don't manage to see any error in it.
Send mail method in System > Configuration is set to "Separate Email" for each section.
Email templates are correctly configured.

What am i doing wrong?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by a bad plugin...i had another problem and resolving it Magento restarted sending confirmation emails.

Here is the link to my question(with answer) : [Source model "" not found for attribute “privacy” Magento 1.9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25097783/source-model-not-found-for-attribute-privacy-magento-1-9?noredirect=1#comment39055595_25097783)

Strange things...

Answer (score 3):

I also struggled with the problem of order e-mails not being sent in CE 1.9.1 but found the problem after a while:

As of Magento CE 1.9.1 Magento doesn't send order emails directly during the order process.
Instead the mails are queued and are sent by the cron.
So make sure to configure the Magento cronjob properly.

Also refer to:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee1141-ce191-responsive-email#cron
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce18-and-ee113-installing#install-cron

Answer (score 1):

There are many things that can cause what you're describing, and most of them are completely unrelated to Magento.

From the limited amount of information you've provided, my guess would be that your email is undeliverable because your domain lacks Sender Policy Framework records (or one of the other major authentication standards like DKIM, SenderID, and Domain Keys), or because the IP/domain you're testing delivery from was formerly occupied by a spammer and has been blacklisted (which happens).

When it comes to testing emails, I usually test delivery to gmail accounts, because they seem to be the most receptive of the public web-based emails. Any kind of company email is usually a bad choice, because they're more likely to have stricter deliverability standards.

Comment: I do not believe that could be a SPF issue...emails for password recovery, user welcomes are correctly sent and received...
Another hypotesis?