# Source model "" not found for attribute “privacy” Magento 1.9

Tags: magento, plugins, attributes, export

I'm getting this error when i try to export Customers via **System > Import/Export > Export**.
How to fix?

Comment: Source model is used to store pre-defined values for attribute. Make sure you correctly enter `'source_model'` value for your attribute other wise update the attribute

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i just answered my own question few minutes ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause was the plugin : Tax Code & Privacy http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/tax-code-privacy.html.
After the uninstallation it left the attribute "privacy" for customer entity.

Solution was to remove manually the attribute in the database table *'eav_attribute'* of Magento.

I simply destroyed the entry where the column *"attribute_code"* was *"privacy"*.